# Substitute for margarine in graham cracker crust

Tags: baking, substitutions, crust

I have a recipe for cheesecake with a graham cracker crust, and the crust recipe calls for melted margarine.  I'd like to make the recipe without hydrogenated oils/trans fats.

I have butter and a non-hydrogenated oil shortening (palm oil).  Can I substitute one of these for the margarine in the crust recipe?  If not, is there something else that would be a good substitute for margarine here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the butter; historically margarine is a simulated butter in the first place, and you will probably get a better product, since butter tastes much better.

You could use the shortening, but it will not help the flavor at all, and doesn't have the approximately 18% water that butter and margarine do, although this usually doesn't matter in a graham cracker crust.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the butter myself, and if you are going to use butter, use good quality butter. It will make your crust taste 10x better for sure.

Comment: Downvote!?  I guess who ever did has not used REAL butter to cook with before.

Comment: It's probably because you recommended a specific brand, which just feels really spammy. I suspect you don't actually work for them, you just like their butter, but still - the question wasn't about brands, so it's out of place here. I'm going to replace it with a more general recommendation. If you don't like this, you can roll back my edit. I'm also removing the nutrition-ish part, which is off topic here.

Comment: I could see where that would be spammy.  Sorry about that.  It is just some great stuff. Everything I have used for it has been better just because it is real butter.  I will not be so brand spacific next time :) to OP though, you should really give it a shot.

Comment: @IazoDev Here in Wisconsin, America's Dairyland, we have no problem finding real butter.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can exchange it with marscapone cheese at room temperature

Comment: Hello Rencia, welcome to the site. Have you tested your recommendation? If yes, please state so. I, personally, have some doubts whether mascarpone would remain stable when baked.

Comment: Hello Rencia. This space is reserved for answers only. I assumed that you are putting forth mascarpone as a suggestion to use to solve the problem, and in this case, it needs no question marks. If you intended to ask if a mascarpone is a good substitute, this is an entirely different question. Please use the "Ask question" button, or this link: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask, to ask whether mascarpone works well in graham crusts.

Comment: Marscapone cheese instead of margerine **will not** make the biscuit base set...